# Can not start MariaDB service on windows 10 machine although I have full admin rights

Tags: windows-10, services, privileges, mariadb

At work I have to use Windows 10 for the first time and I am having a hard time starting a service.

I downloaded the latest version of MariaDB as a .zip from the official homepage at: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.4.8/

Via a command line (started as an administrator) I ran

```
mysql_install_db.exe --datadir=C:\lpDB --service=lpDB --password=root -o --port=3306
```

and got the following output:

```
Running bootstrap
Executing ""C:\Users\NicStar\Applications\DBMS\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe" --no-defaults --console --innodb-page-size=16384 --bootstrap "--lc-messages-dir=C:/Users/NicStar/Applications/DBMS/mariadb-10.4.8-winx64/mariadb-10.4.8-winx64/share" --basedir=. --datadir=. --default-storage-engine=myisam --max_allowed_packet=9M  --net-buffer-length=16k"
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] C:\Users\NicStar\Applications\DBMS\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 10.4.8-MariaDB) starting as process 2756 ...
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 139827; transaction id 21
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\lpDB\ib_buffer_pool
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-10-25 10:35:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191025 10:35:12
Removing default user
Setting root password
Creating my.ini file
Registering service 'lpDB'
Creation of the database was successful
```

Then I tried running the service, first via command line:

```
sc start lpDB
```

but I got an error:

```
[SC] StartService ERROR 5:

Access denied
```

As far as I know I have full admin rights on this machine, but as I said, this is my first time working with windows 10 so maybe I am missing something.

So next I tried running services.exe. I tried to start and stop random services I knew were safe to see whether I can and it all went smoothly. Then I searched for my mariaDB service named lpDB and I tried starting it. I get the same error as a popup now.

I have so far wasted one and a half hours on this and have exhausted all options known to me. I just can not find out what it is that I am missing. Please help.

By the way: I found the troubleshooting website at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installation-issues-on-windows/ but it did not help me. I did run the command prompt with full admin rights and still got the error.

Comment: is there really nobody who knows anything about this? Or did I ask this question on the wrong board? Should it perhaps have been asked on Stackoverflow instead?

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I have so far found no solution to this problem, only a workaround by running the DBMS in a docker container. This is however not a full solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Running the below from the command line will install it as a service in Windows (assuming your path to `mysqld` is correct; I am going by your output above).

```
C:\Users\NicStar\Applications\DBMS\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64\mariadb-10.4.8-winx64\bin\mysqld --install
```

This should result in "MySQL" appearing in the services list from the *Control Panel*, within administrative tools. There, you can set it to autostart at boot, can stop it, start it, restart it, etc.